# Credit cards in irish gas stations

Tags: payment-cards, ireland, northern-ireland

Do gas station in small towns or rural areas in `Northern Ireland` and the `Republic of Ireland` accept credit cards and debit cards for payment?

Comment: Yes, more often than not petrol stations in the rural areas are represented by national chains like Tescos, Jet, Morrisons, and locals like Go.  It's very civilized.  Most of them will have a cash point also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, more often than not petrol stations in the rural areas are represented by national chains like Tesco's, Jet, Morrisons, and locals like Go.  Most of them will have a cash point also.

There are also lots of self-service petrol stations where the pay point is next to the pump and an attendant is not required at all.

Tip: Get a Tesco Loyalty card before leaving and you'll accrue bonus points as your trip progresses.

Comment: Germany is widely considered civilized too but you can not rely on credit card payment here. We are a bit slow in adapting useful technologies . That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: What is the benefit of the bonus points?

Comment: @ectomorph, it can add up [Tesco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesco_Clubcard#Clubcard_Fuel_Save)

Comment: And I can get a coffe machine then? Or do I save money when paying for fuel?